# PHPSPREADSHEET задать формулу

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Как в библиотеке `phpspreadsheet` можно задать формулу `A1 * A2 * A3 / A4?`

Comment: Думаю вопрос стоит адресовать автору репозитория или же дополнить его здесь путем попытки применения. Так как обысно вопросы текстом приняты только для админских вопросов. Кроме того вопрос холиварен.Что есть A1? Ячейка, переменная?

Comment: Точно так же как и значение конкретной ячейки.

Answer (score 0):

```
$spreadsheet
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue(
        'A5',
        '=A1 * A2 * A3 / A4'
    );
```